# Get docstring of present code portion with Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

One of the disadvantages of Jupyter / iPython over Pycharm or Spyder is that I cannot see the documentation of the present code fragment / class / command by default (i.e.: that the referring docstring / signature is not shown automatically).

Is there any plugin / workaround possible to achieve this in a Jupyter notebook as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute a method with `?` and the bottom pane will show up.

Inside the parenthesis of a method use `shift + tab` to bring up documentation pop-up.

[image: Jupyter Notebook - Docstrings]